# Creating 12* Tables as a matrix

Tags: python

Code is designed to create a 12* table with largest value 12*m.

Code returns an empty list, it should return the 12*12 table.

```
from numpy import matrix


def times_twelve(m):

    max_numb = m*12
    list_of_A = []
    for n in range(1 ,13):
        list_of_A.append(max_numb - (12 - n))
    return list_of_A


def twelve_times_table(largest_numb_in_table):

    count = 1
    lists_of_lists_of_twelve = []
    while count >= largest_numb_in_table:
        lists_of_lists_of_twelve.append(times_twelve(count))
        count += 1
    times_table = matrix(lists_of_lists_of_twelve)
    return times_table


print twelve_times_table(12)
```

Am I using the matrix command correctly?

Comment: `while count >= largest_numb_in_table`: that loop won't get very far.

Comment: Ha, right. That is really dumb. Thanks.. :)